# Polymer: How to Validate Iron-AutogrowTextarea

Tags: validation, polymer

I have a text area which I need to validate.

I can not use paper-textarea, because "only `required` and `maxlength` validation is supported."

So, my only choice seems to be iron-autogrow-textarea, which does have a validate().  But I don't know how to make use of the validate().  Can someone please let me know?

My textarea field currently looks like this.

```
<iron-autogrow-textarea
  id='{{name}}'
  class="textareas"
  cols='60'
  bind-value= "{{value}}">
</iron-autogrow-textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get your information for paper-textarea

> "only required and maxlength validation is supported."

The below documentation indicates that it supports almost all the validation:

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=paper-textarea

If you need to implement your own validator, then you need to create two elements

1. Validator that implements 'Polymer.IronValidatorBehavior'
2. Element that implements 'Polymer.IronValidatableBehavior'

Check the ssn validators in the paper-input demo for an e.g. on how to implement those.

https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/tree/master/demo

Comment: "required" and "maxlength" were mentioned in the link that you provided.  I wish the documentation can be more clear.<br>

'code'            <paper-textarea id="my_id" class="textareas" label="" value="{{setting.value}}" auto-validate allowedPattern="{{setting.validation_pattern}}" error-message="{{setting.validation_error_message}}"></paper-textarea>

Comment: "required" and "maxlength" were mentioned in the link that you provided.  I wish the documentation is a bit more clear.

Comment: Its API reference section does have allowedPattern. You can try using it and see if that works or not.